# RFX equivalent data type for _int64 in Informix

Tags: c++, visual-c++, informix

What is the RFX (Record Field Exchange) equivalent data type for `_int64` in the Informix DBMS?

Comment: can you mention what RFX means ?

Comment: @return0 Record Field Exchange

Comment: Instead of adding details via comments improve your question

Comment: Thank u @Rohit ... effort appreciated buddy

Comment: also if you can add up you situation, the difficulty you face and why you need such a conversion, from & into what are you converting etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM Informix databases use the `INT8` type (where 8 means 8 bytes, not 8 bits).

Comment: On the most modern Informix data servers, there's also a type BIGINT which is generally a better choice than INT8 when it is available.  Amongst other things, BIGINT occupies 8 bytes on disk whereas INT8 occupies 10 bytes on disk (and no, it isn't April Fool's Day; I wish that it were).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the extra info. I don't have anything to do with Informix myself, but this might come in handy for those who do.