# RFX equivalent data type for INT8 type in IBM Informix database

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, informix

I am having a field in IBM Informix database of INT8 type to hold 20 digit numbers.  What should be the equivalent data type in MSVC++ (RFX equivalent data type)? I am using Visual C++ and my IDE is Visual Studio 6.0.

The field initial_amount would be declared like this:

```
RFX_Int64(pFX, _T("[initial_amount]"), m_initial_amount);
```

I have written the following custom RFX definition code for the same.
But it seems there is problem with the same.

```
void AFXAPI RFX_Int64(CFieldExchange* pFX, LPCTSTR szName, __int64& value)
{
    ASSERT(AfxIsValidAddress(pFX, sizeof(CFieldExchange)));
    ASSERT(AfxIsValidString(szName));

    UINT nField;
    if (!pFX->IsFieldType(&nField))
        return;

    LONG* plLength = pFX->m_prs->GetFieldLengthBuffer(nField - 1, pFX->m_nFieldType);
    switch (pFX->m_nOperation)
    {
    case CFieldExchange::BindFieldToColumn:
            {
#ifdef _DEBUG
                    // Assumes all bound fields BEFORE unbound fields
                    CODBCFieldInfo* pODBCInfo =
                            &pFX->m_prs->m_rgODBCFieldInfos[nField - 1];

                    if (pODBCInfo->m_nSQLType != SQL_C_DOUBLE &&
                            pODBCInfo->m_nSQLType != SQL_FLOAT)
                    {
                            // Warn of possible field schema mismatch
                            if (afxTraceFlags & traceDatabase)
                                    TRACE1("Warning: double converted from SQL type %ld.\n",
                                            pODBCInfo->m_nSQLType);
                    }
#endif
            }
            // fall through

    default:
    LDefault:
            pFX->Default(szName, &value, plLength, SQL_BIGINT ,
                    sizeof(value), 22);
            return;

    case CFieldExchange::Fixup:
            if (*plLength == SQL_NULL_DATA)
            {
                    pFX->m_prs->SetNullFieldStatus(nField - 1);
                    value = afxDoublePseudoNull;
            }
            return;

    case CFieldExchange::SetFieldNull:
            if ((pFX->m_pvField == NULL &&
                    pFX->m_nFieldType == CFieldExchange::outputColumn) ||
                    pFX->m_pvField == &value)
            {
                    if (pFX->m_bField)
                    {
                            pFX->m_prs->SetNullFieldStatus(nField - 1);
                            value = afxDoublePseudoNull;
                            *plLength = SQL_NULL_DATA;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            pFX->m_prs->ClearNullFieldStatus(nField - 1);
                            *plLength = sizeof(value);
                    }
#ifdef _DEBUG
                    pFX->m_nFieldFound = nField;
#endif
            }
            return;

    case CFieldExchange::MarkForAddNew:
            // can force writing of psuedo-null value (as a non-null) by setting field dirty
            if (value != afxDoublePseudoNull)
            {
                    pFX->m_prs->SetDirtyFieldStatus(nField - 1);
                    pFX->m_prs->ClearNullFieldStatus(nField - 1);
            }
            return;

    case CFieldExchange::MarkForUpdate:
            if (value != afxDoublePseudoNull)
                    pFX->m_prs->ClearNullFieldStatus(nField - 1);
            goto LDefault;

case CFieldExchange::AllocCache:
            {
                    CFieldInfo* pInfo = &pFX->m_prs->m_rgFieldInfos[nField - 1];
                    pInfo->m_pvDataCache = new __int64;
                    pInfo->m_nDataType = AFX_RFX_DOUBLE;
            }
            return;

#ifdef _DEBUG
    //  case CFieldExchange::DumpField:
//  {
//      *pFX->m_pdcDump << "\n" << szName << " = " << value;
//  }
            return;
#endif //_DEBUG

    }
}
```

Will this code work for Visual C++ 6.0 ? If not, then how should I go about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get 19 digits stored in an INT8, not 20.  If you need 20 digits, use a DECIMAL(20,0).

You should use BIGINT rather than INT8; BIGINT occupies 8 bytes on disk whereas INT8 occupies 10 bytes on disk (don't ask).

How does this differ from your previous two questions on RFX and 64-bit integers?

1. [RFX_BigInt Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770018/rfx-bigint-error).
2. [RFX Equivalent Data Type for __int64 in Informix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733226/rfx-equivalent-data-type-for-int64-in-informix).

As for what's possible in MS Visual C++ 6.0, I'm sorry, I have no idea.  Wikipedia says it was released in 1998; that's a little old, isn't it?  The chances are it does not support 64-bit data types, which could well be why you are having problems with 64-bit data types when using it.